# Python - Fitting 2D rectangular data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am writing a program using python 2.7 and am having difficulting pinpointing the best way to interpolate/fit some rectangular data.

I have a bunch of known data points of the format z=f(x,y) where x and y are evenly spaced on a grid.  My x points range from 0 to 100 in increments of 0.1.  My y points range from 0 to 100 in increments of 2.

My issue in interpolating or fitting this data is the large spacing between my y data coordinates.  I am looking for the best way to fit this data so that I can evaluate the height Z for any (X,Y) coordinate pair.  I want the resulting surface to be as smooth as possible.  The conventional methods using griddata, or rectbivariatespline do no produce smooth surfaces - seemingly because the space between my y points is much greater than the space between my x points.

One option I considered was to use polyfit (or something similar) to fit a polynomial to each slice (the Y vs Z curve at each X) then to interpolate these slices together to produce a smoother surface.  This seems like kind of a roundabout way of doing things.  Is that my best option?

*example of fitting a slice to a polynomial:*
[image: fitting data]

If fit to a polynomial, each of my slices (Y vs Z at a fixed X) is roughly gaussian or bimodal.  They are fairly simple distributions.

My goal is to be able to produce a smooth, closely fit surface for display in 3D or on a pcolor style chart.  I need to avoid swings past Zmax and Zmin.  I know this is an issue when using splines.

*my goal:*

[image: goal surface]

Thank you for any help you can provide.  I will watch this thread carefully and respond quickly if you need any elaboration.

**EDIT:**

From what I have read, it seems like what I am looking for is a *shape preserving* interpolation method in python for 2d data.  I need something along the lines of pchip for matlab, but for a surface.  I have looking through all the documentation and can't find anything shape preserving that will give me a smooth surface.

Comment: I'm away from my desk but I do believe there are regularized spline interpolation methods. May be worth looking into.

Comment: Did you try [map_coordinates](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html)?

Answer (score 2):

> conventional methods using griddata, or rectbivariatespline do no 
>   produce smooth surfaces - seemingly because the space between my
>   y points is much greater than the space between my x points"

You should try scaling your y-coordinates appropriately --- at least griddata assumes an euclidean metric i.e. that the length scales for all dimensions are similar.

If you on the other want shape-preserving interpolation, see my answer [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/31879) However, such an interpolation will not do any smoothing, so maybe this is not what you want after all.

Comment: Thank you for the shape preserving solution.  I will attempt to implement it this afternoon.  When you say the pchip method will not do any smoothing, it will still produce a smoother surface than say, linear interpolation - correct?  Since the peaks will be rounded instead of jagged points?

That is what I gather from reading this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Interpolating_a_data_set

Comment: Yes, IIRC it will produce a surface with continuous derivative, but one that will still interpolate through all data points.

Answer (score 0):

You might try my BSD-licensed  numpy and scipy based curve and surface fitting library at the Google Code repository:

http://code.google.com/p/pyeq2/downloads/list

It has many examples, including Python parallel programming for performance.  Since it is free, it won't cost anything to try it.

James